# Single session limit for sftp user

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, users

I just want to set limit on sftp connection.
Like if i set a session limit 1 so that user can make only 1 connection from that username. I don't want ip based or port based limit.

I have tried `/etc/security/limits.conf` with `user hard maxlogins 1`

It's always works only if that user is already active via ssh connection, if that user is not connected via ssh already than he is able to make multiple connections.

Comment: similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416498/set-a-limit-on-concurrent-ssh-sftp-connections-to-2-per-user

Answer (score 0):

MaxSessions, set in sshd_config may do what you are asking.
 `man -s sshd_config`

*/etc/security/limits.conf* does not do what you want, because that manages SSH logins. SFTP does *not* login with ssh, it just uses the ssh protocol.

Comment: yes i have tried. But it's not helps Subsystem sftp  internal-sftp

Match User username
       X11Forwarding no
       AllowTcpForwarding no
       PermitTTY no
       ForceCommand internal-sftp
       MaxSessions 1 but still not helps